# Python Discord bot for Midjourney

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I found a Py [Script on a Site](https://medium.com/@neonforge/how-to-automate-midjourney-image-generation-with-python-and-gui-automation-ac9ca5f747ae), but it's not workin always.
The error suggests that the bot is freezing somewhere but I'm not sure why.
[The Download Script](https://medium.com/@neonforge/how-to-create-a-discord-bot-to-download-midjourney-images-automatically-python-step-by-step-guide-3e76d3282871) is not working aswell. It's not completly broken but only picks up a few images. No Errors, it just stops saving the images to the output folder.

the error

```
WARNING  discord.gateway Shard ID None heartbeat blocked for more than 60 seconds.
Loop thread traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\dc_bot\main.py", line 94, in <module>
    client.run(discord_token)
  File "C:\Users\arko7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 860, in run
    asyncio.run(runner())
  File "C:\Users\arko7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 190, in run
    return runner.run(main)
  File "C:\Users\arko7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
  File "C:\Users\arko7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 640, in run_until_complete
    self.run_forever()
  File "C:\Users\arko7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 321, in run_forever
    super().run_forever()
  File "C:\Users\arko7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 607, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "C:\Users\arko7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1922, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "C:\Users\arko7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\events.py", line 80, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "C:\Users\arko7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 441, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\dc_bot\main.py", line 63, in on_message
    while prompt_counter < len(prompts):
```

The original Code by Michael King

```
import time
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import pyautogui as pg


discord_token = "YOUR_DISCORD_TOKEN"

# Using readlines()
prompt_file = open('prompts.txt', 'r')
prompts = prompt_file.readlines()

prompt_counter = 0

load_dotenv()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="*", intents=discord.Intents.all())


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot connected")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    global prompt_counter

    msg = message.content
    print(message)

    while prompt_counter < len(prompts):
        # Start Automation by typing "automation" in the discord channel
        if msg == 'automation':
            time.sleep(3)
            pg.press('tab')
            for i in range(1):
                time.sleep(3)
                pg.write('/imagine')
                time.sleep(5)
                pg.press('tab')
                pg.write(prompts[prompt_counter])
                time.sleep(3)
                pg.press('enter')
                time.sleep(5)
                prompt_counter += 1

        # continue Automation as soon Midjourney bot sends a message with attachment.
        for attachment in message.attachments:
            time.sleep(3)
            pg.write('/imagine')
            time.sleep(5)
            pg.press('tab')
            pg.write(prompts[prompt_counter])
            time.sleep(3)
            pg.press('enter')
            time.sleep(5)
            prompt_counter += 1

    # Stop Automation once all prompts are completed
    quit()

client.run(discord_token)
```

I tried to implement some changes with chatgpt but it did not work, here is the modified code:

```
from promts.animals import write_prompts_to_file_animals
from promts.rooms import write_prompts_to_file_rooms
from promts.country_architecture import write_prompts_to_file_country_architecture

import time
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import pyautogui as pg
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import asyncio

load_dotenv()
discord_token = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

n_promts = 3

# Write the promts in the promts.txt


file_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'prompts.txt')
with open(file_path, 'w') as f:
    f.write('')
    print("Prompts deleted. Starting fresh!")

#write_prompts_to_file_animals(n_promts)
#write_prompts_to_file_rooms(n_promts)
write_prompts_to_file_country_architecture(n_promts)


# Using readlines()
prompt_file = open('prompts.txt', 'r')
# 'promts/radom_animals_niji', 'promts/radom_animals', 'promts/ramdom_rooms', 'promts/random_country_architecture'
prompts = prompt_file.readlines()

prompt_counter = 0


load_dotenv()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="*", intents=discord.Intents.all())


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot connected")


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    global prompt_counter

    msg = message.content
    print(message)

    while prompt_counter < len(prompts):
        # code for automation
        prompt_counter = 0  # reset prompt counter after all prompts have been completed

        # Start Automation by typing "automation" in the discord channel
        if msg == 'automation':
            await asyncio.sleep(3)  # wait for 3 seconds without blocking the event loop
            pg.press('tab')
            for i in range(1):
                await asyncio.sleep(3)
                pg.write('/imagine')
                await asyncio.sleep(5)
                pg.press('tab')
                pg.write(prompts[prompt_counter])
                await asyncio.sleep(3)
                pg.press('enter')
                await asyncio.sleep(5)
                prompt_counter += 1

        # continue Automation as soon Midjourney bot sends a message with attachment.
        for attachment in message.attachments:
            await asyncio.sleep(3)
            pg.write('/imagine')
            await asyncio.sleep(5)
            pg.press('tab')
            pg.write(prompts[prompt_counter])
            await asyncio.sleep(3)
            pg.press('enter')
            await asyncio.sleep(5)
            prompt_counter += 1

    # Stop Automation once all prompts are completed
    return()

client.run(discord_token)
```

the download script to download the generated images

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import requests
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from PIL import Image
import os

discord_token = "PASTE_YOUR_DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN"

load_dotenv()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="*", intents=discord.Intents.all())
directory = os.getcwd()
print(directory)

def split_image(image_file):
    with Image.open(image_file) as im:
        # Get the width and height of the original image
        width, height = im.size
        # Calculate the middle points along the horizontal and vertical axes
        mid_x = width // 2
        mid_y = height // 2
        # Split the image into four equal parts
        top_left = im.crop((0, 0, mid_x, mid_y))
        top_right = im.crop((mid_x, 0, width, mid_y))
        bottom_left = im.crop((0, mid_y, mid_x, height))
        bottom_right = im.crop((mid_x, mid_y, width, height))
        return top_left, top_right, bottom_left, bottom_right

async def download_image(url, filename):
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:

        # Define the input and output folder paths
        input_folder = "input"
        output_folder = "output"

        # Check if the output folder exists, and create it if necessary
        if not os.path.exists(output_folder):
            os.makedirs(output_folder)

        # Check if the input folder exists, and create it if necessary
        if not os.path.exists(input_folder):
            os.makedirs(input_folder)
        with open(f"{directory}/{input_folder}/{filename}", "wb") as f:
            f.write(response.content)
        print(f"Image downloaded: {filename}")
        input_file = os.path.join(input_folder, filename)

        if "UPSCALED_" not in filename:
            file_prefix = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
            # Split the image
            top_left, top_right, bottom_left, bottom_right = split_image(input_file)
            # Save the output images with dynamic names in the output folder
            top_left.save(os.path.join(output_folder, file_prefix + "_top_left.jpg"))
            top_right.save(os.path.join(output_folder, file_prefix + "_top_right.jpg"))
            bottom_left.save(os.path.join(output_folder, file_prefix + "_bottom_left.jpg"))
            bottom_right.save(os.path.join(output_folder, file_prefix + "_bottom_right.jpg"))
        else:
            os.rename(f"{directory}/{input_folder}/{filename}", f"{directory}/{output_folder}/{filename}")
        # Delete the input file
        os.remove(f"{directory}/{input_folder}/{filename}")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot connected")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print(message.content)
    for attachment in message.attachments:
        if "Upscaled by" in message.content:
            file_prefix = 'UPSCALED_'
        else:
            file_prefix = ''
        if attachment.filename.lower().endswith((".png", ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".gif")):
            await download_image(attachment.url, f"{file_prefix}{attachment.filename}")


    # use Discord message to download images from a channel history, example: "history:50"
    if message.content.startswith("history:"):
        download_qty = int(message.content.split(":")[1])
        channel = message.channel
        async for msg in channel.history(limit=download_qty):
            for attachment in msg.attachments:
                if "Upscaled by" in message.content:
                    file_prefix = 'UPSCALED_'
                else:
                    file_prefix = ''
                if attachment.filename.lower().endswith((".png", ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".gif")):
                    try:
                        await download_image(attachment.url, f"{file_prefix}{attachment.filename}")
                    except:
                        time.sleep(10)
                        continue

client.run(discord_token)
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi do you have any experience with Python?

Comment: A reminder: Per Midjourneys TOS any kind of automation will get your account banned.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Midjourney Terms of Service](https://docs.midjourney.com/docs/terms-of-service), and brought up by Moritz, you are not permitted to automate asset generation;

> You may not use automated tools to access, interact with, or generate Assets through the Services.

Which means I recommend you do not continue with this in a public nor private environment as it could result in you being banned/blacklisted from Midjourney.

As well as this, I recommend you do not try and utilise AI tools (Specifically ChatGPT, which has outdated info) for code implementation. Albeit that they are good at some things, not everything is perfect.